# Generating the union of possible subsets

Tags: sets, subset

I want to calculate the union of possible subsets within each set of the family of sets.

I use the following code:

```
s = {a, b, c} 
t = {X,{},{a},{a,b}} 
GatherBy[Subset[t, #] & /@ Subsets[s]] 

(* {{{{a, b, c}, {}, {a}, {a, b}} ⊂ {}}, {{{a, b, c}, {}, {a}, {a, b}} ⊂ {a}}, 
 {{{a, b, c}, {}, {a}, {a, b}} ⊂ {b}}, {{{a, b, c}, {}, {a}, {a, b}} ⊂ {c}}, 
 {{{a, b, c}, {}, {a}, {a, b}} ⊂ {a, b}}, 
 {{{a, b, c}, {}, {a}, {a, b}} ⊂ {a, c}}, {{{a, b, c}, {}, {a}, {a, b}} ⊂ {b, c}}, 
 {{{a, b, c}, {}, {a}, {a, b}} ⊂ {a, b, c}}} *)
```

But I actually want to obtain

```
{{{{{} ⊂ {}}, {{a}} ⊂ {a}}, {{} ⊂ {b}}, {{}} ⊂ {c}}, 
 {{{a}, {}, {a, b}} ⊂ {a, b}}, {{{a}, {}} ⊂ {a,c}}, 
 {{{}} ⊂ {b, c}}, {{{a, b, c}, {}, {a}, {a, b}} ⊂ {a, b, c}}}
```

How can I get this result?

Continuing, I need the set after the above like this: {{},{{}∪{a}},{},{},{{}∪{a}∪{a,b}},{{}∪{a}},{},{{}∪{a}∪{a,b}}} Thank you..

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I have edited your question to give it a more sensible title and tags, but it is not very clear what you are actually looking for. Can you please explain your problem in words?

Comment: I want to calculate the union of possible subsets within each set of the family of sets.

Comment: You're using `GatherBy` wrongly. It takes two arguments, but you have only supplied it with one argument. Did you mean to do something like this `GatherBy[Subsets[s], # ⊂ t &]` ?

Comment: I want to calculate the largest set of subsets in t within each group of the family of sets (s).

Comment: So that the set ant its largest subset from t  each of them  within parentheses

Comment: As @Domen already suggested, please, take a moment to properly describe in words the task at hand and edit the original question. Do not include important information in the comments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my best guess at what you're trying to do. I'd break the problem into two steps. First define a function that selects the subsets for a given set, and second map that function over the list of sets.

```
FindSubsets[candidates_, set_] := Subset[Select[candidates, ContainsAll[set, #] &], set]

FindSubsets[{{a}, {x}, {}}, {a, b}]
(* Subset[{{a}, {}}, {a, b}] *)
```

Now use it on your data. I think your expected result was wrong, both in structure and in content, so my result doesn't match yours exactly. Apologies if I misunderstood.

```
s = {a, b, c};
t = {X, {}, {a}, {a, b}};

result = FindSubsets[t, #] & /@ Subsets[s];
result /. F -> Subset // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: That is perfect, thank you.

Comment: Hello, can you help me?

Comment: Again, I need to get the following results: